# Conditional read access to DynamoDB table with AWS Amplify

Tags: database, authentication, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I'm building an application with AWS Amplify, where I have three DynamoDB tables: `Users`, `Posts` and `Subscriptions`.

1. users can make posts
2. users subscribe to other users
3. user `A` can only see posts by user `B` if user `A` is subscribed to user `B`

Points 1. and 2. are easy to implement with standard graphQL mutations. But I'm stuck at how to implement 3. in an elegant way. Currently what I do is to use a lambda resolver.

Given inputs "user `A` wants to see user `B`", the lambda resolver does the following:

1. Query `Subscriptions` table to see if there's a document for "user `A` subscribed to user `B`"
2. if such a row exists, query `Posts` table and return documents. If not, return nothing.

This logic required two round trips, but since dynamo is fast I'm OK with this trade-off. There are other downsides though, so I'm wondering if there's a more Amplify-native way to do this? Some magic DynamoDB and @auth trickery perhaps?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using multiple tables to store the data, the multiple query approach is your only option.

You *can* use transactions when mutating items across multiple tables, which is useful when you want to perform an operation based on a condition on an item in another table(s).  But when it comes to a read operation, you have no such option.

Aside from re-designing your tables to support this access pattern, I don't think two reads is particularly bad.

If you wanted to handle authorization logic outside of DDB, you may want to look into AWS IAM and it's documentation on [Fine-Grained Access Control](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/specifying-conditions.html).  Among other features, IAM can restrict access to specific items in a table based on certain primary key values.